# Staging environment for Azure Mobile Services using Code First Migrations

Tags: azure-mobile-services, entity-framework-migrations, staging

I seem to have trouble understanding a concept with Azure Mobile Services that are using .NET backend with Code First and migrations enabled.

Currently I have deployed a "productive" instance of AMS, let's say it's called "AMD". It is running at amd.azure-mobile.net. Database structure has been created using Enable-Migrations and Add-Migration. This is all fine now for this productive instance, it is running and is fully functional.

Now I want to create an INT instance to have a separate environment for tests etc. I want to name it differently, say "AMDINT". It should run at amdint.azure-mobile.net and should also have a separate database, to make it impossible to break stuff in production.

Originally I thought I could pull it off like this:
1) Create the new instance under amdint.azure-mobile.net with a new database to go with it
2) Create a web.config transform for a newly created configuration called "INT" (primarily to change the MS_MobileServiceName value to the new name)
3) Download the publishing profile of the new instance, import it, make it use the "INT" configuration and deploy it

The new bits apparently get deployed, but whenever I hit an endpoint that requires DB access, an error will be generated in the logs and it says

*Database initialization failed. Could not initialize one or more objects in schema 'amdint'. Please ensure that the database connection string is correct. For more details on the error, please see the inner exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Database initialization failed. Could not initialize one or more objects in schema 'amdint'. Please ensure that the database connection string is correct. For more details on the error, please see the inner exception. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: User does not have permission to perform this action.*

So I used Azure User Management Console (AUMC) to see if permissions were missing for the user that is being specified in the connection string in the configuration tab of the new service, but the user was present for that database. I also edited the user's permissions to include every possible right, but this did not change anything.
Then I noticed that the migrations files specify a database schema for the Up() and Down() methods. For a test, I changed these strings from "amd.tablename" to "amdint.tablename" and was pretty confident I had nailed it.

However, this still brought the same error. So I used the database user's credentials from the connection string and opened database editor from the management console in the browser, and saw that with all the added rights it can edit the database schema just fine (created and deleted a table for testing purposes). However, no single table has been created by the Initializer; the database was blank.

But since I was able to edit, I somehow believe that either the error message about insufficient permissions is misleading or that I am looking at the wrong place.

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish what I am trying to do? I don't want to have separate Visual Studio projects for production and INT, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're running into is the issue that Mobile Services creates a special schema user that has rights to only tables in that schema. This schema has the same name as your mobile service. So, even if the two databases are on the same DB server, the connection string for a DEV mobile service wouldn't work for PROD, and vice versa.

Here are some suggestions to make your setup easier:

1. In the Azure Portal, Mobile Services doesn't allow modifying the connection string that it creates for you, which is called MS_TableConnectionString. I recommend that in your case, you create a new connection string with a different key and use that for each of your services, e.g., `AMD_TableConnectionString`. Make sure that for each service, the database user has access to each schema (more on that in a minute).
2. To use the new connection string, change your super constructor call in your DbContext class, e.g., `base("name=AMD_TableConnectionString")`.
3. Use the application setting `MS_MobileServiceName` in your web.config and/or the Azure Portal to set the schema for your service. This is use by the Mobile Service Entity Framework initializer.

   NOTE: If you're already using separate databases for DEV and PROD, you have the option of using the same schema name for both your DEV and PROD instances, which might make testing and setup easier.

   Either way, the database user in the connection string must have full permissions to whatever schema name you specify in `MS_MobileServiceName`.
4. (You probably have this part working.) Make sure that the Mobile Services SQL Generator is run. It will automatically run if you set an Entity Framework database initializer, but some folks like to have all database changes done through DB migrations. In that case, follow this tutorial here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-code-first-migrations/#using-code-first-migrations-without-an-initializer